# SQL, xQuery: Find duplicates

Tags: sql, xquery, xquery-sql

I have a moderate knowledge of SQL and xpath, but none of xquery. How might I write a query to get all records where the XML contained within one field has two instances of the same element which also contains matching data of a sub element.

Let me explain by example:

Table: `Fred`
Table Fields: `id, time, xmlone, xmltwo.`
I want to find all records in this table where the `xmlone` has something like the below:

```
<!--xmlstart-->
<!--...any number of elements-->
<elementone position="1">
  <subelea>2010-01-01</subelea>
  <subeleb>hg72</subeleb>
  <subelec>George</subelec>
</elementone>
<!--...any number of elements here (may not end at same level)-->
    <elementone position="2">
      <subelea>2010-01-01</subelea>
      <subeleb>hg72</subeleb>
      <subelec>John</subelec>
    </elementone>
<!--xmlend-->
```

Note I want only matches where `subelea` and `subeleb` are matching. Also there may be duplicates of `elementone`, but I am not concerned with that unless the data from `subelea` and `subeleb` match.

Answer (score 1):

```
(: Self-join on all <elementone/> :)
for $i in //elementone, $j in //elementone
where $i != $j
(: Compare `$i` and `$j` on the subelements that should be equal (or whatever) :)
and $i/subelea eq $j/subelea
and $i/subeleb eq $j/subeleb
(: Return result :)
return $i
```

If you need to take care of duplicates (on element level, does not care if two elements with exactly the same contents are in the input), wrap everything in parentheses and add `/.` (step operations take care of duplicates).

```
(
  for $i in //elementone, $j in //elementone
  where $i != $j
  and $i/subelea eq $j/subelea
  and $i/subeleb eq $j/subeleb
  return $i
)/.
```

Comment: Thanks! - but could you simplify for a noob. As I said "I have a moderate knowledge of SQL and xpath, but none of xquery". How might I merge this into a complete statement?

Comment: It is a complete statement running totally fine in BaseX for the data you provided and should in all other XQuery processors, too. But I overlooked you tagged your question SQL-XQuery - better include this information in your question, too. I'm sorry not being able to provide you with information how to call some XQuery, but probably you will be able to copy-paste this from other questions (just click on that tag). Provide all XML as input to my query and it should run fine.